# use Neo4j as Triple Store in remote server

Tags: neo4j, triplestore

I had used Tinkerpop and openrdf sail to connect the neo4j at local well.

```
    String dB_DIR = "neo4j//data";

    Sail sail = new GraphSail(new Neo4jGraph(dB_DIR));

    sail.initialize();
```

that I can import ttl or rdf file then query0

but now I want to connect the remote neo4j.

How can I use neo4j jdbc in this case ?

or the Tinkerpop blueprint has the way can do it ?
( I did some searching work but no good answer )

Comment: see http://michaelbloggs.blogspot.de/2013/05/importing-ttl-turtle-ontologies-in-neo4j.html for importing ttl into neo4j

Comment: Sorry for my inaccurate question above. The main problem is kind of how can I access Neo4j remotely with Tinkerpop blueprint or there is some way like that.
The information you provided is helpful ! That's another way to do the import.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Sesame Repository API](http://rdf4j.org/sesame/2.7/docs/users.docbook?view#Programming_with_Sesame) for accessing a Sail object.

Specifically, what you need to do is wrap your `Sail` object in a `Repository` object:

```java
Sail sail = new GraphSail(new Neo4jGraph(dB_DIR));
Repository rep = new SailRepository(sail);
rep.initialize();
```

After this, use the `Repository` object to connect to your store and perfom actions, e.g. to load a Turtle file and then do a query:

```java
RepositoryConnection conn = rep.getConnection();
try {
    // load data
    File file = new File("/path/to/file.tll");
    conn.add(file, file.getAbsolutePath(), RDFFormat.TURTLE);

    // do query and print result to STDOUT
    String query = "SELECT * WHERE {?s ?p ?o} LIMIT 10";
    TupleQueryResult result = 
        conn.prepareTupleQuery(QueryLanguage.SPARQL, query).evaluate();

    while (result.hasNext()) { 
       System.out.println(result.next().toString());
    }
}
finally {
    conn.close();
}
```

See the [Sesame documentation](http://rdf4j.org/sesame/2.7/docs/users.docbook?view#Programming_with_Sesame) or [Javadoc](http://rdf4j.org/sesame/2.7/apidocs/index.html) for more info and examples of how to use the Repository API.

(disclosure: I am on the Sesame development team)

Comment: Thanks for answer and the good way to do import and query. 
by this "Sail sail = new GraphSail(new Neo4jGraph(dB_DIR));"
Is there any way not to you local neo4j's data directory. Can I connect to a remote neo4j server like "http:192.168.1.1:7474" ?

Comment: I don't think so. You could conceivably use Sesame's remote capabilities by using the wrapped Sail as part of a Sesame Server, but that is difficult to set up because the Tinkerpop blueprint sail implementation does not provide the required configuration classes.